# How can I get the coordinates of a mouseClick relative to the entire viewable document?

Tags: javascript

I need a way to find the coordinates of a mouseclick relative to the entire document. I am aware of pageX and pageY, but these values do not take in account the true entire document, or rather what I really mean is, these values do not consider the currently viewable document, AND the left over scrollable document. So while the X value is fine because this page does not scroll on the X-axis, it means that the Y value will change depending on WHERE the user is on account of the ability to scroll.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add to the "clientY" the value of the "window.scrollY" position in the event sender (if you use the "onmousemove" event)

I've made an example for you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Test</title>
<style>
    body {
      height: 100;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #mouse {
      position: fixed;
      width: 500px;
      height: 200px;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-top: -100px;
      margin-left: -250px;
      font-size: 50px;
    }    
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mouse"></div>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>
<script>
    onmousemove = function(e){
      document.getElementById("mouse").innerText = e.clientX + " - " + (e.clientY + window.scrollY)  + " - " +  window.scrollY
    }
    
    let testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
    for (let index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
      let tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
      tempDiv.innerText = "test" + index;
      testDiv.appendChild(tempDiv);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate you taking the time to respond with this much detail! That being said, why would my window.scrollY value always be 0 regardless of the presence of a scrollbar?

Comment: window.scrollY is 0 unless you scroll down (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY). Did you scroll? Notice that in my example the "mouse" div updates only when the mouse move